# Docker: listen for .sql changes and re-provision database

Tags: docker, provisioning

I'm looking for a design pattern to "listen" for file changes in a directory (they are all .sql files with a Makefile) and execute a command if any change.

In my repository I have three types of data:

1. node.js files
2. PostgreSQL config
3. SQL files for provisioning PostgreSQL

If node.js files (1) change, then the node.js container must restart. If PostgreSQL config (2) changes, the PostgreSQL DB must restart. Both these are easy. But if SQL files change (3) then I need to run a `make` command to process the `.sql` files using `psql` without restarting node.js or PostgreSQL.

The challenge is that this `make` command would normally exit after completion. So if it were created in the form of a dockerfile, it would get continuously restarted unnecessarily by docker once it exits. Other than adding a hacky `sleep 99999999` type of command to my `Makefile`, are there any commonly accepted practices for this type of "run once then exit" requirement using docker?

Comment: Use inotify 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify

or in Python pyinotify

http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @user2915097 I'm aware of many solutions for watching for file changes. In fact docker includes such a solution of its own, so that's why I'm asking if there's a "docker way" to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a common "Continuous Integration" pattern. Files are commited into a source code revision system like Subversion or Git. Changes to these files are then automatically detected by a build server like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) which performs the "docker build" and "docker push" (Assuming you're using a local registry to distribute built images within your organisation).